# Treat symbols as words in prog modes

Tags: syntax, navigation

There are a number of commands in Emacs which apply to "words."  Examples include `forward-word`, `kill-word`, `upcase-word`, `mark-word`, `transpose-words`, etc.  The definition of "word" seems to vary a bit between the commands.  For example, `forward-word` will stop at an underscore within a word (e.g. `foo_bar`) but `mark-word` does not stop at the underscore.

**Is it possible to change the definition of "word" when I am in a prog mode so that Emacs will use the appropriate word boundaries for the syntax of the current language?**

When I am in `c-mode` I want `forward-word` to skip over underscores, and when I am in `lisp-mode` I want `forward-word` to skip over both hyphens and underscores, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Emacs should already use "*the appropriate word boundaries for the syntax of the current language*".  If it does not then file a bug for the major mode for that language.

But maybe you don't really mean *words*.  Maybe you mean **symbol** syntax, not word syntax. Emacs distinguishes the two.

For symbol syntax, use symbol commands, not word commands: `forward-symbol`, etc. *From your description, this is what you really want.*

If you feel you really want to use a word function on a symbol, you can **change the syntax category of particular characters** *to have word-constituent syntax instead of symbol-constituent syntax.* But generally this is not what you want to do and you should not need to do it.

See the Elisp manual for info about character syntax. And see the Emacs manual and the Elisp manual for commands and other functions that operate on symbols (not Lisp symbols, but text with symbol syntax, in whatever language).

And keep in mind that operations on sexps are often useful also for acting on symbols: `C-M-f` (`forward-sexp`), `C-M-t` (`transpose-sexps`), etc.

Comment: `C-M-f` is bound to `forward-sexp` and behaves nothing like what you describe.  You are right that what I want is to navigate by symbols, but I don't see that option.

Comment: @nispio `forward sexp` is essentially `forward-symbol` most of the time, with the added versatility of also going over matching braces. You should give it a chance.

Comment: @Malabarba I strongly disagree that `forward-sexp` is a close approximation of `forward-symbol`. For starters, it can confusingly jump you over entire functions, landing you hundreds of lines from where you started. It also jumps over argument lists, etc. And try this: given the following lisp code `(global-set-key [remap list-buffers] 'ibuffer)` place your cursor in the middle of the word `remap` and run `forward-sexp` a few times.  It **raises an error** when it reaches the closing `]`.  No thanks.

Comment: @nispio I always use a combination of sexp and word navigation. That way I can avoid any of these problems, while having the versatility of both. But it's all a matter of preference. ;-) If you know you'll never miss word navigation, `superword-mode` might be your guy.

Comment: Sorry, I should not have suggested that `C-M-f` and `C-M-t` act on symbols (they act on sexps).  I will edit to correct that impression.  But you can certainly bind `forward-symbol` to any key you like, if you find it particularly useful.  There is no `transpose-symbols`, but you can write one, again, if you think it is useful.

Comment: `(fboundp 'forward-symbol) => nil`

Comment: @nispio: I guess it was added in Emacs 24.4 (in library `subr.el`).

Comment: @nispio: NO! Sorry; I should have known better. It's been around forever. They simply moved it from `thingatpt.el` to `subr.el` in Emacs 24.4.  So just `(require 'thingatpt)`. Better yet, use [`thingatpt+.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/thingatpt%2b.el).

Answer (score 11):

Take a look at `superword-mode` and `subword-mode`. Superword treats underscores as part of a word instead of a boundary, so `foo_bar` *would be treated as a single word*.
Subword does the opposite but for camelCase, so `fooBar` is treated as two words instead of one.

It sounds like the behavior you want is for `cc-mode` to use `superword-mode`.

```
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'superword-mode)
```

I would recommend reading over the source for `subword-mode`, as even if those two modes are not doing exactly what you want, they should show you how to change the word detection behavior.

Longer discussion on [emacsredux](http://emacsredux.com/blog/2013/04/21/camelcase-aware-editing/), and [ergomacs](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_subword-mode_superword-mode.html).

Comment: Is it possible to make `superword-mode` play nice with `paredit`? For example, `paredit-forward-kill-word` does not delete the whole word (containing underscores) when `superword-mode` is enabled.

Comment: It's changing the definition of a word, and `paredit` is respecting that, so I think it's doing what is asked of it.

Comment: The thing is that paredit is *not* respecting that. `paredit-forward-kill-word` does not kill the same word defined by `superword-mode`.

Comment: Oh I misread. Hmm. Just took a look at `paredit-forward-kill-word` and it looks like it's doing it's own parsing. So might be able to swap that out, but probably not.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood your question, you could modify the language syntax table, e.g. For c++:

`(modify-syntax-entry ?_ "w" c++-mode-syntax-table)`

`M-x apropos` then look up of syntax-table should help you too.