# What's the difference between words and symbols?

Tags: elisp, major-mode, syntax

When defining a syntax table for a major mode, I can define both word constituents and symbol constituents.

When should I use each? For example, given a programming language that writes variables in snake case `foo_bar`, should `_` be part of a word or symbol?

Comment: The default `c-mode` that comes with emacs uses `_` as a symbol constituent but not a word constituent. So I expect there to be a good reason for that. Not to mention the plethora of navigation commands that will work as expected. Principle of least surprise and all that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Word constituents: ‘w’**

Parts of words in human languages. These are typically used in variable and command names in programs. All upper- and lower-case letters, and the digits, are typically word constituents.

**Symbol constituents: ‘_’**

Extra characters used in variable and command names along with word constituents. Examples include the characters ‘$&*+-_<>’ in Lisp mode, which may be part of a symbol name even though they are not part of English words. In standard C, the only non-word-constituent character that is valid in symbols is underscore " _ ".

Courtesy of [gnu.org](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-Class-Table.html#Syntax-Class-Table)

> When should I use each? For example, given a programming language that writes variables in snake case foo_bar, should _ be part of a word or symbol?

It depends one what you want to achieve. I'll say, '_' should be part of word. That way, foo_bar will be treated as one word.

Please throw an eye to that [question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/983/treat-symbols-as-words-in-prog-modes), there is an interesting answer talking about superword-mode and subword-mode

Comment: Since c-mode treats `_` as a symbol constituent, why do you suggest treating it as a word constituent?

Comment: @WilfredHughes Sorry but, nobody here was talking about c-mode. Sure, he should be careful about the mode is working on. And as I told in my response, it's only for the case he may want to treat foo_bar as one word. Please check that [question](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/983/treat-symbols-as-words-in-prog-modes)

Comment: Please don't use word syntax for characters like `_`, since that completely defeats the distinction between words and symbols.  If you like your `M-f`, `M-b` and friends to move by identifiers rather than by words, then rather than change the major mode's syntax table you should use `superword-mode`.

Comment: When writing your major-mode, _don't_ make symbols and words be the same thing. A lot of people _use_ the distinction, and you'd be making their life harder. People who don't like the distinction already have the option of `superword-mode`.

Comment: I do like to use `M-f` to move by symbols, so I bind it to `forward-symbol`. Anyway, @Stefan and @Malabarba: would you then suggest that `!` and `?` should also be symbol constituents? Sounds like words should only be [a-zA-Z0-9] in all programming languages.

Comment: @WilfredHughes: indeed, the definition of words should pretty much never be changed.

Answer (score 4):

This answer addresses your question title: "*What's the difference between words and symbols*". It does not speak only to the body of your question, which is about symbol syntax, which has been answered well by @Nsukami.

There are two *very different* meanings of the word *symbol* in Emacs:

1. **symbol syntax**, which involves *word-constituent characters* **plus** *symbol-constituent characters*. This can apply to *any* mode, in particular any programming mode/language. @Nsukami described this meaning quite well.
2. **Emacs-Lisp symbols**.  This is not a syntax category.  A Lisp symbol is a Lisp entity, or object, which has certain characteristics: a **name**, a **plist** (property list), and potentially a **value** and a **function** definition.

   By default, the value cell and function cell are empty, and the plist is is the empty list (`nil`). Lisp functions `symbol-name`, `symbol-value`, `symbol-function`, and `symbol-plist` return the components.

Note, BTW, that there is no mention of these things in the Emacs manual; they are covered only in the Elisp manual. And more significantly, perhaps: There is **no index entry** that matches "*symbol*" for the first meaning (syntax).  **All** index entries that include the term "*symbol*" refer to the second meaning (Lisp symbol). In particular, there is no entry that contains both "*symbol*" and "*syntax*".  Whether there should be such an index entry, I don't know (probably). But this can give you some idea of the **importance to Lisp of symbols as Lisp objects**.

For more info, see:

- The Elisp manual, node [`Symbols`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/elisp.html#Symbols)
- The Elisp manual, node [`Syntax Class Table`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-Class-Table.html#Syntax-Class-Table)
- The [Glossary](http://www.emacswiki.org/Glossary) on Emacs Wiki.

Comment: thanks a lot for explaining the 2 different meanings of the word symbol.

Answer (score 2):

This is explained [in the ELisp manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-Class-Table.html#Syntax-Class-Table).

Emacs uses terminology from Lisp. What Lisp and Emacs calls a *symbol* is what many other programming languages call an *identifier. That's the name of a variable, function, etc.

A *word* is a run of letters or digits with no intervening punctation.

Most programming languages allow the underscore `_` character in identifiers, in addition to letters and digits. Some languages, such as Lisp, allow more. In programming languages, characters such as `_` that can appear in identifiers have the class “symbol constituent” `_`; letters and digits have the class “word constituent” `w`.

Commands that act on words treat a sequence of word constituents as a word. Commands that act on expressions (e.g. `forward-sexp`) move by whole identifiers at once. Syntax highlighting usually treats all symbol constituents identically.