# Deleting whole variable name on M-backspace

Tags: text-editing, symbols

Is there a way to configure emacs, so that when I hit M-backspace it would actually remove the whole variable? If I have a variable like `my_dummy_variable` I need to hit M-backspace three times in order to remove the name?

Comment: Maybe the answers to this [question](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/983/treat-symbols-as-words-in-prog-modes) can help.

Comment: this is really related to emacs not C and not C++, suggest remove `c` tag,

Answer (score 2):

You can use the built-in `backward-kill-sexp`.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-DEL") 'backward-kill-sexp)
```

This has the unwanted effect of adding whatever was deleted to the kill ring.

To fix this you can try:

```
(defun backward-delete-sexp (arg)
     (interactive "P")
     (delete-region (point)
            (progn (backward-sexp arg) (point))))
```

Comment: actually, you probably want <M-backspace>, not <M-DEL>

Comment: `(let ((kill-ring)) (backward-kill-sexp arg))` may be a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for `superword-mode`.  From its documentation:

> Superword mode is a buffer-local minor mode.  Enabling it remaps
>   word-based editing commands to superword-based commands that
>   treat symbols as words, e.g. "this_is_a_symbol".
>
> The superword oriented commands activated in this minor mode
>   recognize symbols as superwords to move between superwords and to
>   edit them as words.